# how to pass in ant.build.clonevm?

Tags: ant

I'd like to pass properties(-Dname=val) down to junit&java tasks from the Ant command line. The problem is the -3rd party- build file doesn't pass those properties down.

I was thinking `ant.build.clonevm` could help, but the [manual says](http://ant.apache.org/manual/clonevm.html)

> Note that this has to be a system property, so it cannot be specified
>   on the Ant command line.

So, can I use this for the above purpose, and how? If not, any other alternatives?
Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ANT_OPTS environment variable instead.

> set ANT_OPTS=-Dxxx=value

xxx is your property